# Php CRUD app: populate column by looping through database table

Tags: php, foreach

I am working on a CRUD app and I run into this problem:

In my database there is a **users** table with fields like *first_name*, *last_name* and so on.

I pull data from the "users" table and display in he browser like so:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>First name</td>
            <td><?php echo $get_users[0]['first_name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td><?php echo $get_users[0]['last_name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $get_users[0]['email']; ?>"><?php echo $get_users[0]['email']; ?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td><?php echo $get_users[0]['city']; ?></td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But the table actually has tens of fields not just the four you can see above.

My question is: Who can I *hardcode the first column only* and for the second one just *loop through the database* and populate every table cell?

Comment: What have you tried? Good to have your expected output, but include the php code of your attempt, and describe what are you having trouble with. Regards!

Comment: why do you want to hardcode the first column?

Comment: Well, the first column describes the values in the second one in a user friendly (human readable) manner.

Comment: what about email field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-borderd">
    <tbody>
     <?php foreach ($get_users[0] as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=str_replace('_', ' ', ucfirst($key))?></td>
            <td><?=htmlspecialchars($value)?></td>
        </tr>
     <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```